# Python len not working

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In the code below, I am trying to use len(list) to count the number of strings in an array in each of the tags variables from the while loop. When i did a sample list parameter on the bottom, list2, it printed 5 which works, but when i did it with my real data,it was counting the characters in the array, not the number of strings. I need help figuring out why that is and i am new to python so the simplest way possible please!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)

#pprint(data)

# calc number of alert records in json file
x = len(data['alerts'])
count = 0
while (count < x):
    tags = str(data['alerts'][count]    ['tags']).replace("u\"","\"").replace("u\'","\'")
    list = "[" + tags.strip('[]') + "]"
    print list
    print len(list)
    count=count+1

list2 = ['redi', 'asd', 'rrr', 'www', 'qqq']
print len(list2)
```

Comment: give a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 4):

Your list construction `list = "[" + tags.strip('[]') + "]"` creates a `string`, **not** a `list`. So yes, `len` works, it counts the characters in your string.

Your tags construction looks a bit off, you have a dictionary of data (`data['alerts']`) which you then convert to string, and strip of the '`[]`'. Why don't use just get the value itself?

Also `list` is a horrible name for your variable. This possible clashes with internal values.

Comment: Also, calling a variable `list` is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = "[" + tags.strip('[]') + "]"
print list
print len(list)
```

Ironically, `list` is a string, not a list. That's why calling `len` on it "was counting the characters in the array"

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that your variable is a list rather than a str,
try:

```
print(type(yourList))
```

if it shows that it is a str, then try this:

```
len(list[yourList)
```

hope this answers your question

and when you want to establish a list variable, try this:

```
myList = []
for blah in blahblah:
    myList.append(blah)
```

I think these definitely solved your problem, so I hope you noticed this part.